# Run sbt tests in gitlab ci

Tags: sbt, gitlab-ci

I have a play 2.4.x project. I would like to use gitlab to do CI.

How can I run tests in [ci.gitlab.com](https://ci.gitlab.com/)?

My `gitbal-ci.yml` file looks like the following but its obviously wrong.

```
tests:
  script: "apt-get install -y sbt && sbt test"
```

I get the error

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package sbt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use directly an `SBT` image.

This `gitbal-ci.yml` worked in my case (handles also caching):

```
image: "sbtscala/scala-sbt:17.0.2_1.6.2_3.1.3"

variables:
  SBT_VERSION: "1.2.8"
  SBT_OPTS: "-Dsbt.global.base=sbt-cache/.sbtboot -Dsbt.boot.directory=sbt-cache/.boot -Dsbt.ivy.home=sbt-cache/.ivy"

cache:
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" # contains either the branch or the tag, so it's caching per branch
  untracked: true
  paths:
    - "sbt-cache/.ivy.cache"
    - "sbt-cache/.boot"
    - "sbt-cache/.sbtboot"
    - "sbt-cache/target"

stages:
  - test

test:
  script:
    - sbt test
```

This is from: [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46330544/2750966)

Comment: I tried with the official sbt docket image "sbtscala/scala-sbt:17.0.2_1.6.2_3.1.3" and it worked fine for me on gitlab. ref: https://github.com/sbt/docker-sbt

Answer (score 1):

To install sbt on a Debian based distribution, you have to run the following steps

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

See the [official sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Installing-sbt-on-Linux.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
 test:
      stage: test
      image: mozilla/sbt
      script:
        - sbt test
```

Comment: Official sbt docker images https://hub.docker.com/r/sbtscala/scala-sbt