# how to prevent gitlab ci from downloading sbt every time?

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, gitlab-ci, sbt-plugin

We have a `play2/scala` application which we are building with gitlab ci.

Our `.gitlab-ci.yml` (at least the important part) looks as follows:

```
image: hseeberger/scala-sbt

variables:
  SBT_GLOBAL_BASE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/cache/.sbt"
  IVY2_CACHE_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/cache/.ivy2"
  SBT_BOOT_DIR:  "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/cache/.sbt/boot"
  M2_HOME_DIR: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/cache/.m2"

before_script:
  # Log the sbt version
  - sbt sbt-version

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - ./build.sh
```

with `build.sh`:

```
sbt -Dsbt.global.base=$SBT_GLOBAL_BASE_DIR \
  -Dsbt.ivy.home=$IVY2_CACHE_DIR \
  -Dsbt.boot.directory=$SBT_BOOT_DIR \
  compile
```

Unfortunately, our pipeline always runs for around 30-40 minutes with all the steps (build, verification, deploy). Most of the time it spends by downloading `sbt` over and over again what is *really* annoying.

I might not know enough about `gitlab ci runners` but from my understand, by using [hseeberger/scala-sbt](https://hub.docker.com/r/hseeberger/scala-sbt/~/dockerfile/) as the image, `sbt` should be globally available and there should be no need to download it.

Then also [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/test-scala-application.html#add-gitlab-ci-yml-file-to-project) solution from gitlab would not be necessary.

Anyhow, I would be glad if `sbt` would not be downloaded totally 6 times during each deployment whenever the server runs any `sbt` command.

Can someone explain me how to use the right `image` or the `image` in the right way or otherwise how I can cache the `sbt` stuff?

## Update

Over the last days I fought a lot with `docker` and `gitlab ci`. I found that this problems is pretty much the same as described in  [don't downloading the internet](http://blog.flurdy.com/2014/11/dont-download-internet-share-maven-ivy-docker.html).  It seems that this is some hard task to have all the dependencies and should be best done by mounting them. That's unfortunately not possible as such on a shared gitlab ci runner.

I went on and discovered [sbt-docker](https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker) which allows you to build docker containers from a `build.sbt` file. With the [package basic approach](https://github.com/marcuslonnberg/sbt-docker/blob/master/examples/package-basic/build.sbt) I tried to include all the locally available dependencies for the project into the container as [global sbt plugins](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Global-Settings.html#Global+Settings+using+a+Global+Plugin). But also this didn't help.

My last discovery was this answer regarding the [`maven` solution](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15167#note_15206811) and tried to translate that into our `sbt` project:

#### .gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: hseeberger/scala-sbt

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: -Dmaven.repo.local=/cache/maven.repository

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - staging
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - sbt compile -Dsbt.ivy.home=/cache/.ivy2 -Dsbt.global.base=/cache/.sbt/0.13 -Dsbt.boot.directory=/cache/.sbt/boot -Dsbt.repository.config=/cache/.sbt/repositories
```

I can access the `gitlab ci` logs again. They look basically as follows:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /builds/kwiqjobs/backend/project
[info] Updating {file:/builds/kwiqjobs/backend/project/}backend-build...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.5.4 ...

[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.5.4 ...

[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-routes-compiler_2.10;2.5.4 ...

[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-routes-compiler_2.10;2.5.4 ...

[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.6 ...

[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.10;1.1.1 ...

[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.10;1.1.1 ...

... a **lot** more

[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-twirl;1.1.1!sbt-twirl.jar (1033ms)
[info] downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-native-packager/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.3/jars/sbt-native-packager.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-native-packager;1.0.3!sbt-native-packager.jar (954ms)
[info] downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-web/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.3.0/jars/sbt-web.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-web;1.3.0!sbt-web.jar (1010ms)
[info] downloading https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-js-engine/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.1.3/jars/sbt-js-engine.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-js-engine;1.1.3!sbt-js-engine.jar (1147ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/play/twirl-api_2.10/1.1.1/twirl-api_2.10-1.1.1.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.typesafe.play#twirl-api_2.10;1.1.1!twirl-api_2.10.jar (89ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] commons-io#commons-io;2.4!commons-io.jar (48ms)

a **lot** more
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 228 Scala sources and 4 Java sources to /builds/kwiqjobs/backend/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] 'compiler-interface' not yet compiled for Scala 2.11.8. Compiling...
[info]   Compilation completed in 17.735 s
[success] Total time: 149 s, completed Jan 20, 2017 2:22:52 PM
Build succeeded
```

And I would like to get rid off all the *downloading*.

Comment: The solution from gitlab you linked to is not included in your build script, are you using it or not? Also please post the relevant parts of the output.

Comment: No, it's not included. I am mostly wondering whether it should not be possible to avoid downloading `sbt` _at all_ with the hseeberger/scala-sbt image. On this docker image, `sbt` is already installed. Is there then any need to cache or install it?

Comment: It seems that I cannot access the logs right now, gitlab.com isn't responding. But you will see that after `sbt sbt-version` has been called, all `sbt` dependencies will be resolved and downloaded. Afterwards, when `build.sh` is being called, it will start all over again downloading them. Then, on `verification.sh` and `deploy.sh` **again** _everything_ will be downloaded again. Is the [gitlab solution](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/test-scala-application.html#add-gitlab-ci-yml-file-to-project) the one I need to go with? Can I do some additional caching there?

Comment: You are downloading all the dependencies and building the application 3 times it seems. I added most of the options you can use.

Comment: Please have a look at https://leonard.io/blog/2017/05/gitlab-ci-caching-for-sbt-projects/ on how to enable caching. I tested it, and it works as expected.

Comment: ah, wow! We solved it now our way but it seems that that work. Thanks! Should we give it as an answer here and upvote it?

Comment: @stubbi You're right, I will prepare an answer (with proper recognition of the original source)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you don't want to use custom made images, the best solution is to use Gitlab CI's [caching mechanism](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#cache).

It's a little hard to get it right, but [this blog post](https://leonard.io/blog/2017/05/gitlab-ci-caching-for-sbt-projects/) describes how to do it for SBT.

## Example `.gitlab-ci.yml`

Quoted from the blog post, minor errors corrected by myself:

```
# some parts originally from https://github.com/randm-ch/units-of-information/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

image: "hseeberger/scala-sbt"

variables:
  SBT_VERSION: "0.13.9"
  SBT_OPTS: "-Dsbt.global.base=sbt-cache/.sbtboot -Dsbt.boot.directory=sbt-cache/.boot -Dsbt.ivy.home=sbt-cache/.ivy"

cache:
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" # contains either the branch or the tag, so it's caching per branch
  untracked: true
  paths:
    - "sbt-cache/.ivy/cache"
    - "sbt-cache/.boot"
    - "sbt-cache/.sbtboot"
    - "sbt-cache/target"

stages:
  - test

test:
  script:
    - sbt test
```

## Second example, also including `apt-get` caching

This is what I used for my project, usable for more general use cases and Docker images:

```
image: java:8

stages:
  - test

variables:
  SBT_VERSION: "0.13.9"
  SBT_OPTS: "-Dsbt.global.base=sbt-cache/.sbtboot -Dsbt.boot.directory=sbt-cache/.boot -Dsbt.ivy.home=sbt-cache/.ivy"
  SBT_CACHE_DIR: "sbt-cache/.ivy/cache"

cache:
  key: "$CI_BUILD_REF_NAME" # contains either the branch or the tag, so it's caching per branch
  untracked: true
  paths:
    - "apt-cache/"
    - "sbt-cache/.ivy/cache"
    - "sbt-cache/.boot"
    - "sbt-cache/.sbtboot"
    - "sbt-cache/target"

before_script:
  - export APT_CACHE_DIR=`pwd`/apt-cache
  - mkdir -pv $APT_CACHE_DIR
  - ls $APT_CACHE_DIR || echo "no apt-cache dir found"
  - apt-get -o dir::cache::archives=$APT_CACHE_DIR update -y
  - apt-get -o dir::cache::archives=$APT_CACHE_DIR install apt-transport-https -y
  # Install SBT
  - mkdir -pv $SBT_CACHE_DIR
  - ls $SBT_CACHE_DIR || echo "no ivy2 cache fir found"
  - echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
  - apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 642AC823
  - apt-get -o dir::cache::archives=$APT_CACHE_DIR update -y
  - apt-get -o dir::cache::archives=$APT_CACHE_DIR install sbt -y
  - sbt -v sbtVersion

test:
  stage: test
  script:
     - sbt -v sbtVersion
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 things you can do:

1. own docker image
2. cache
3. artifacts
4. use own caching solution

The best solution will be a mix of them all.

1. You can build your own docker image with all the dependencies you need, it's the fastest solution as it won't have to download everything but it will introduce another piece of the puzzle you need to take care of. You can use the [in-built gitlab repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698767/how-to-prevent-gitlab-ci-from-downloading-sbt-every-time) for storing it and have gitlab build it and then [use it](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-an-image-from-a-private-docker-registry).
2. You can use [cache](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#cache) in Gitlab CI jobs so it won't have to download everything all the time. The default cache for sbt seems to be ~/.ivy2 so add

> ```
> cache:
>   paths:
>     - ~/.ivy2/
> ```

As the first lines in your gitlab file to use the caches for each stage.

3. Define the target directory as the [artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/#artifacts) to pass it between builds and so you don't have to build it on each stage.

> ```
> artifacts:
>   paths:
>     - target/
> ```

4. You can store the files you need to cache in your own s3/minio/nfs if the options supplied by gitlab are not enough. This will be a very custom solution so you will have to find your own way around it.

Comment: Thanks so far! I will test them. But regarding 1: Why do I need to create my own docker image if the one I am using from the public repository should have already the sbt dependency which it downloads during the build anyway? Why is that not working?

Comment: @stubbi Well, I'm not familiar with stb but I think it's pulling the dependencies of your project or self updating. At least it looked like that when i tried running an example project.

Comment: I found the problem. The sbt version in the container and in our project must match! We where using `0.13.11` while in the container there is `0.13.13`. That speeds up everything but there is still the dependencies which should be in the container then. And at best they should also always be up to date. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34384657/how-to-run-a-sbt-project-in-docker-by-using-sbt-docker-or-writing-a-docker-file) question here with a hint on [sbt native packager docker plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/docker.html) and will try that now.

Comment: I updated the question. Might you have a look again? Maybe you can see better now where the problem is.